# Excel solver using relative references?

Tags: microsoft-excel, solver

I have a requirement to use Solver with a certain set of data, and although I know how to use Solver with one set of data, there are a few other rows of data that I need to use it for, and then it becomes repetitive as Solver only uses absolute references.

Is there a way out? Can I somehow apply the same criteria just with different rows and make Solver recalculate a result for all these rows?

Someone said that using `INDIRECT` could be an option, but I didn't get any explanation of how.

Comment: It's hard to say based on your description. It could be that "Named Ranges" will help you. Hit CTRL+F3 to open the range editor. In addition to naming a static range, you can define ranges using formulas. For example: If you have a huge column of values, you can use this technique to make your range end at a specific value within that column. It's very powerful.

Comment: You might get a response if you post an example of your data and what you are trying to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume you are using VBA. If that's not the case, this won't make much sense.

I recommend reviewing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36671991/use-solver-in-vba-with-loop-in-rows) discussing challenges using Solver in VBA.

To use references for setting up Solver (e.g. SetCell:=), I have found this works, whereas most other methods do not.

```
Set SetRng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
SetAddress = Split(SetRng.Address(external:=True), "[")(0) & Split(SetRng.Address(external:=True), "]")(1)
SolverOK SetCell:=SetAddress
```

Where SetAddress is Dim'd as a string.